# what is returning a function?

Tags: python

so, my professor has taught us this and i don't get it. i run the code in jupyter notebook and nothing happens. can someone tell me what is this code supposed to do? it has something to do with returning a function which i don't really understand.

```
def make_logger(target):
    def logger(data):
        with open(target, 'a') as f:
            f.write(data + '\n')
    return logger

foo_logger = make_logger('foo.txt') #foo.txt will be created if not there already
foo_logger('Hello')
foo_logger('World')
```

i tried running it in python which gave me a syntax invalid error.

Comment: Do you see a `foo.txt` file created in the working directory?

Comment: Also, please share what syntax error you're getting in Python shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python everything is an object. Just like any variables that you define, a function also is an object.

I would highly recommend to read through this beautiful post which goes in length at describing [this](https://dbader.org/blog/python-first-class-functions)

In the above program, that you pasted, let us analyze the below line

```
foo_logger = make_logger('foo.txt')
```

It is returning logger function as the result.

Now the logger function can in itself take any argument as a data and write it to a file,
so when you call the

```
foo_logger('Hello')
foo_logger('World')
```

It will then go ahead and append this to the file named foo.txt and you will have the file contents as
Hello
World

You can check that by doing a cat foo.txt
And the function is accurate, doesn't produce any syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

`make logger` returns a function (`logger`) that takes an argument and writes it to  a the file provided by `make_logger`'s argument. The following lines that call `foo_logger` pass data to it, and have it write that data to the log file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the code, the code written by you ran fine and doesn't have any syntax errors.

```py
def make_logger(target):
    def logger(data):
        with open(target, 'a') as f:
            f.write(data + '\n')
    return logger

foo_logger = make_logger('foo.txt') #foo.txt will be created if not there already
foo_logger('Hello')
foo_logger('World')
```

This program ran, created, and saved the file `foo.txt` at the same path as the `.py` file present.

So, It basically ran as follows.

- This line `foo_logger = make_logger('foo.txt')` returned a function via function call in which the destination of the file is passed as the `target` parameter and saved as the variable. So, you can call it later.
- Yes, you heard it right. We can assign functions as variables in python, pass them arguments inside functions and return them via functions as well.

e.g. Assigning a function as a variable.

```py
def plus_one(number):
    return number + 1

add_one = plus_one
add_one(5)
```

Output:

```
6
```

- This line `foo_logger('Hello')` Called the function with parameters as input. It writes 'Hello' in the already created `foo.txt` file and saved it.
- Again, this line `foo_logger('World')` was called, and append the `foo.txt` file with 'World' as text in it.

So, The output of this program saved in file will be

```
Hello
World
```

This is the same concept being used in `Python Decorators` to wrap any function with some additional functionalities to an existing object without modifying its structure. You can understand it better [here](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/decorators-python)